# Send Firebase crash notifications to group

Tags: firebase, notifications, firebase-crash-reporting, firebase-console

I am trying to send crash notifications to a group.

For individual users, I can add them through the IAM permissions - and they can subscribe in their profile what notifications they will receive.

For (Google email) groups, I can add one again through IAM permissions; but no members of that group actually receive any notifications - and since it is a group, I can't set what notifications it can get through any profile - as there is none.

Am I missing something? Thanks.